# How to wrap an OpenCart web app in mobile app?

Tags: react-native, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap, react-native-ios, opencart-3

First of all, I hope the question is not too much general.

I want to wrap my existing website which is done by OpenCart 3 in mobile app.

After googling a lot and checking many websites and articles, the only practical instruction what I found is doing this using PhoneGap. The instruction is titled as [How to use PhoneGap to port quickly your web app to a native iOS and Android device](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2012/01/26/how-to-use-phonegap-to-port-quickly-your-web-app-to-a-native-ios-and-android-device/). As explained there, the web project should be rendered as `HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript`.  But not explained how to do it with an OpenCart project!

Is it possible to make a native app in both Android and IOS using PhoneGap or any other platforms? How to do it?

Comment: You can learn about the Android Webview, though opencart website would be too big. Consider making an api